# Can Android Service outlive Application object?

Tags: android, android-service, android-lifecycle

So, the question is pretty self-explanatory. Can custom `Application` object (the one I declare in `AndroidManifest.xml`) be destroyed earlier than the launched `Service`, provided that `Service` is **not** launched in another process?

My intuition says it's not possible, since we can access `Application` object in `Service` by calling `getApplication()`, plus I've not seen anything like this in documentation, but `Android` is full of unexpected funny behaviors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Can custom Application object (the one I declare in AndroidManifest.xml) be destroyed earlier than the launched Service, provided that Service is not launched in another process?

Each process gets its own `Application` object, and that object lives as long as the process does. Hence, any component (e.g., a `Service`) cannot outlive the `Application` from its own process.

Answer (score 3):

When the app process gets killed, all services in this process also get killed. So no, a service can not outlive an Application object – see [Process Lifecycle in the Service docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html).